# Selecting a cell in Excel using function

Tags: excel

In an Excel how do I select a cell from a different column in the same row using a function

For example, I have the following lookup table

```
   X        Y
+-------+--------+
| Name  | phone  |
+-------+--------+
| James | 100    | <=== table 1 (lookup)
| Mike  | 200    |
| Anne  | 300    |
+-------+--------+
```

and I try to fill the following `phone` column with the *correct* and *non-empty* values that are in the above *lookup* table

```
    A       B
+-------+--------+
| Name  | phone  |
+-------+--------+
| James | 101    | <=== table 2
| Mike  |        |
| James | 200    |
+-------+--------+
```

Now I want to know how to specify the first parameter as I apply the formula to the entire `phone` column of *table 2* just so whatever is in the `Name` column of *table 2* becomes the lookup value. So far I just have:

```
=VLOOKUP(???, X2:Y4, 2, false)
```

What should be my first parameter in the above formula ?

Comment: You want to use the name, so `=Vlookup(A2,$X$2:$Y$4,2,False)`, no?  Although, for `James`, that will return `100`, not `101`. Why would it be `101`?

Comment: And why would James part II return 200?

Comment: the name is not just `James`,  I wish to correct the `phone` column in `table 2` with different names such as Mike and Anne using the lookup table. Examples I have found online all have a fixed value, but I am looking for different lookup values that are `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and so on...

Comment: Use the formula provided by @BruceWayne - `=Vlookup(A2,$X$2:$Y$4,2,False)` - the `A2` will update when you autofill the formula/drag it down the column because `A2` is not an absolute reference.

Comment: @Raystafarian because it is incorrect in table 2 and the formula would be ` =VLookup(A3, $X$2:$Y$4, 2, False)` to correct the phone value using the lookup table. The thing is that I want to apply the formula to the entire column so lookup value isn't fixed.

Comment: You mean that if the value in Table 2, is different than Table 1, you want to replace the Table 2 value with Table 1's?

Comment: A formula cannot refer to itself.  You will need to put the formula in another column that uses an IF() to determine which value to use either the returned value of the VLOOKUP or the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Table 2, you need an additional column. Let's start in C2, you can use this formula:

`=If($B2=VLOOKUP($A2,$X$2:$Y$4,2,False),"",VLOOKUP($A2,$X$2:$Y$4,2,False))`

This will check the value in B2. If it matches the value in Table1, nothing is returned (`""`), but if they're different it will return the Table1 value (the `Vlookup()` formula).